# Draw google road maps : Fixing the error in route

Tags: google-maps, gps, geocoding

Now I am working on mobile application Which fetches the gps location in certain intervals send location data to server. The server draw Google route map based in this information.

Please help me solve the following scenario

Sometime the gps coordinates marked on the Opposite route actually traveled and make the route Completely error.

For example I travelled on a [**route like this (On google map)**](https://www.google.co.in/maps?saddr=39.9044328,-75.1504317&daddr=39.8894888,-75.2026698%20to:39.8825823,-75.2489458&hl=en&sll=39.893493,-75.199608&sspn=0.075599,0.169086&geocode=FbHkYAIdoEuF-w;FVGqYAIdkn-E-w;FVaPYAIdzsqD-w&mra=ls&t=m&z=13)

[image]

But I get [**map like (On google map)**](https://www.google.co.in/maps?saddr=39.9044328,-75.1504317&daddr=39.8894888,-75.2016698+to:39.8825823,-75.2489458&hl=en&sll=39.889305,-75.201655&sspn=0.001181,0.002642&geocode=FbHkYAIdoEuF-w%3BFVGqYAIdeoOE-w%3BFVaPYAIdzsqD-w&mra=ls&t=m&z=13)

[image]

The point B is fetched/Marked on the **parallel road**

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Move the point onto the correct road?  If you have too much data to do it manually, you will need to create an algorithm to detect the incorrect point and fix it (which is not going to be easy).

Comment: @geocodezip do you know about any similar algorithm or logic of removing the incorrect points.

Comment: If I did, I would have pointed you to it.

Answer (score 0):

try alexander library for route drow

compile 'com.github.jd-alexander:library:1.1.0'

example:

```html
private void startRouting() {

        
        LatLng  origin = new LatLng(18.01455, -77.499333);
        LatLng destination = new LatLng(18.0145600, -77.491333);
        Routing routing = new Routing.Builder()
                .travelMode(Routing.TravelMode.DRIVING)
                .alternativeRoutes(false)
                .withListener(new RoutingListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onRoutingFailure(RouteException e) {
                        Log.e("onRoutingFailure: ", e.getMessage());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onRoutingStart() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onRoutingSuccess(ArrayList<Route> routes, int shortestRouteIndex) {
                        if (routes != null && routes.size() > 0) {
                            for (Route route : routes) {
                                List<LatLng> latlngs = route.getPoints();
                                try {

                                    Random rnd = new Random();
                                    int color = Color.argb(200, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), 0);
/*                                    int color1 = Color.argb(225, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));
                                    int color2 = Color.argb(225, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));
                                    int color3 = Color.argb(225, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));*/
                                    mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().addAll(latlngs).color(color).width(12.0f));

                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                    Log.e("onRoutingSuccess: ", e.getMessage());
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "An internal error occurred!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                            //showBottomSheet(routes.get(shortestRouteIndex));
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onRoutingCancelled() {
                        Log.e("onRoutingCancelled: ", "Routing cancelled");
                    }
                })
                .waypoints(origin, destination)
                .build();
        routing.execute();


    }
```